# Why is Settings.bundle causing iTunes/adhoc to say my iPhone App is not valid?

Tags: ipad, settings.bundle, ota

Any time I have an app with a settings bundle it will not install OTA or through iTunes. It will work fine on the device under a dev cert but ota or iTunes or installing through organizer fail with a dist cert.

My settings bundle has a single toggle from Apples template file. It works correctly in that it won't allow email (within my app) if it is toggled.

This is the second app I have made that will not ota install with a settings bundle. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue and after hours of investigations I found out that the "settings.bundle"'s resource fork was lost because I was creating/modifying it on a FAT32 partition. You should create the settings.bundle on a OSX partition or repair the resource fork.